# Resources for Android absolute beginner

Tags: java, android, objective-c, ios, android-widget

I am a complete Android and C in general noob,

I have done a lot of web programming (which I am imagining is largely irrelevant here), some javascript (not jQuery just raw JS), I have also developed a .net app and done a course in java programming at uni last semester,

I know that Android uses Java in some places and C in others, I have looked at the SDK documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

My aim is to build a simple dashboard widget that pulls data on a minute-by-minute basis from a JSON/JSONP API, I have thus far struggled to find any decent tutorials for real Android noobs such as myself, especially in the app widget category, If anyone knows of any good resources (online or books are fine) consisting of basic good practises, start-up guides and quick tutorials to get me up to speed would be great as I have absolutely no idea where to start (especially in the C end of things), I have found the SDK documentation does have some good stuff but it isn't exactly what I am after (built on very old builds of Android and thus most of the cool new features aren't integrated or taken into account).

Any recommendations would be very much appreciated!

On a side note, If all goes well with Android I would also be looking to move onto iOS so Objective-C start-up and tutorials would be great (Visual Quick Pro guide style would be perfect!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally started reading and *understanding* the Android [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html). Then I downloaded the Android [ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html) (Development Toolkit), configured it on [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) as well as the SDK (**including samples**).

Once that's set up, I started with the [ApiDemos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html). You find its source code directly in the downloaded SDK `<sdk-install-location>/samples/android-9/ApiDemos`. Try to debug the code in the IDE, modify it and see how it reacts.

Finally, have fun :)

Comment: Thanks @Juri this is more what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I started with the Android developer documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

If that isn't as organized as you'd like for a complete beginner, you might want to try the FAQ since they have a lot of good tutorial links there, which happen to be very thorough:

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/index.html

Once you get the basics, which the tutorials will do for you, the first link to the developer guide will be where you'll spend most of your time.  There are even links in the guide for getting started with your IDE of choice, or getting started using no IDE at all.

To get a more specific answer, you'll have to ask a more specific question.